# Issue in width of the container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed header and right aside of 260px. I have `three columns` with `height 100%`.The `content area to be a fluid-container that is 12 column wide`.

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="secondary-aside"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the fiddle i am working on. The width of the cols are breaking with the layout.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxusJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really clear what you mean by *The width of the cols are breaking with the layout.*

Try it this way :

```
html, body, .container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%; /*keep html and body 100% */
    margin:0;
    background:lightgray
}
.container {
    display:table;
    width:calc(100% - 260px);/*keep container 100% - 260px */
    border-spacing:0.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand; you want the container to be fluid, but then you have columns within it that have a fixed width?

How you could do it is:

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="secondary-aside"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%;  
}

.header { 
    height: 60px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

.container { 
    overflow: auto; 
  height: 100%; 
}

.secondary-aside { 
    width: 25%;
  float: right; 
    background: red; 
  height: 100%; 
}

.content { 
    width: 75%;
  float: left;
  background: #777;
  overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-sm-4 { 
    height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  width: 33.3333%;
  float: left;
}
```

Would that help?

Comment: *Would that help?* - certainly not....BS doesn't require you to design so much of custom CSS!! :)

Comment: @Frank, add this to the top of the CodePen, I forgot to copy/paste:

    html, body { 
 height: 100%;  
    }

Setting both HTML and BODY to height: 100% makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use so much of custom styles in BS.
Check the responsiveness of the page in `http://www.responsinator.com/`

Check this out.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .secondary-aside {
        width: 25%;
        float: right;
        background: #000000;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="header">i am the header</div>
<div class="secondary-aside col-sm-4">ff</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color: red">r</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"style="background-color: green">g</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4"style="background-color: blue">b</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```